# sqlite query for range search having text for ios app

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table with columns as `LowerFrequency`, `HigherFrequency` and `ID`. The frequencies entered have a suffix of `khz` or `mhz`. I want to search a specific frequency by checking the range it falls in i.e between the lower and higher frequencies and fetch the respective `ID`.

The query I implemented was as below but it returns a wrong output:

```
select tablename.ID where "100 khz" between tablename.LowerFrequency and tablename.HigherFrequency;
```

I know the reason is because of the `khz` that follows the integer. But I need some suggestions to handle this as I am not in a situation of changing the whole DB file because it is time consuming.

I will be integrating this DB with my iPhone app. So any solutions in Objective C would also be appreciated. I mean some kind of conversion.

Comment: The problem is not Objective C specific, it appeared to be SQL problem.

Comment: true but i ment if there is any way i could read khz or mhz from the table and do the conversion from kHz to 1000 or so in my .m files.

Comment: Only if you pull all of the data and filter in Obj-C. You should change what is stored in the DB so it doesn't have the KHz / MHz suffix...